# Toss a coin and roll a die, $x = \text{outcome on the die and } y = \text{number of heads }$

Tags: probability

Toss a coin and roll a die, $x = \text{outcome on the die and } y = \text{number of heads }$

(a) Find the joint mass function

(b) Find $F_{X, Y}(2, 0) $

Answer:

(a)

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
y/x & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ \hline
 0& 1/12 & 1/12 & 1/12 & 1/12 & 1/12 & 1/12\\ \hline
 1 & 1/12 & 1/12 & 1/12 & 1/12 & 1/12 & 1/12\\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

Since, there are only 0, 1 possible heads, and 6 possible die outcomes, thus all the probability is $$\frac{1}{2 \cdot 6}$$

(b) $$F_{X, Y}(2, 0) = P(X \leq 2, Y \leq 0)$$

No clue

$P(X \leq 2) = P(X = 1) + P(X = 2) = 1/6 + 1/6 = 2/6 = 1/3$

$P(Y \leq 0) = P(Y = 0) = 1/2$

How do I do this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your table to sum the probabilities of each outcome that satisfy the conditions. That would be $X=1,Y=0$ and $X=2,Y=0$. That would be a total probability of $\dfrac{1}{12}+\dfrac{1}{12} = \dfrac{1}{6}$.

Alternately, you can use the product principle on your results.

$$P(X\le 2)\cdot P(Y\le 0) = \dfrac{1}{3}\cdot \dfrac{1}{2} = \dfrac{1}{6}$$